# Novel Document Class \LaTeX

Tags: document-classes, novel

I'm writing a book chapter about \LaTeX, so obviously I want to use the correct formatting. How can I do this in the novel document class?

```
\documentclass{novel} % v. 1.52.
% Almost all settings are defaults.
\SetHeadFootStyle{3}
\SetTitle{Novel Document Class} % only footer, with page number
% The following PDF/X standard is typical for USA print-on-demand.
% However, not every P.O.D. service needs PDF/X these days.
\SetPDFX[CGATSTR001]{X-1a:2001}
\begin{document}

\LaTeX

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73618/is-there-a-class-for-typesetting-novels

Comment: Trying to write "a book chapter about LaTeX" using the `novel` class looks like an exercise in futility, since it seems to prevent you including any *output* from the LaTeX formatting that you are describing, unless you jump through hoops. Just use `memoir` or `scrbook.`

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of `novel` class. The comment by @alephzero is correct. The `novel` class is quite inappropriate for the usage situation. In particular, you cannot include PDF or vector drawings, and you would need to use a lot of verbatim (with possible layout consequences).